# jQuery DataTable - delete cookies

Tags: jquery

I have code:

```
function DataTable() {
    $('#displayData').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "aoColumns": [
                      { "mDataProp": "name" }
        ],
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
            oSettings.jqXHR = req.query('GET', url, aoData, function(responseServer, status, xhr) {
                json = responseServer.dataListCustomer;
                fnCallback( json );
//HERE
              }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  return showError(exception);
                });
        }
      } );
}
```

Where is HERE I want delete cookies which dataTable saved, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want dataTables to retain the state of the table, use the `bStateSave` parameter on initialisation:

```
$('#displayData').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bStateSave": false, // <--
    /* ... rest of your settings .. */
});
```

Internally dataTables uses quite a few cookies, and manually deleting them will become painful to maintain and probably cause you some weird behaviour.

Comment: I must bStateSave on true, because i want to retain the state. Futhermore I want delete cookie when I want

Comment: Which cookie are you trying to delete?

Comment: Saved by bStateSave, but only in cases specified by me

Comment: Or how Can I delete cookie by jQuery which have "displayTable" in name? Of course, includes not only the name of the displayTable